# Adding my launcher to the Unity Launcher automatically. How?

Tags: unity, command-line, .desktop, launcher

Based on official documentation:

> In order to add your launcher to the Unity Launcher on the left, you
>   select and drag it onto the Launcher panel. Alternatively, you can
>   place your .desktop file at /usr/share/applications/ or at
>   ~/.local/share/applications/. After moving your file there, search for
>   it in the Dash (Windows key -> type the name of the application) and
>   drag and drop it to the Unity Launcher. Now your launcher (.desktop
>   file) is locked on the Unity Launcher!

It means, that you can add a launcher manually via "drag and drop".
But, is it possible to do this programatically?

I can explain why I am asking about it:

I have my own scpirt, it downloads the latest version of Eclipse IDE, creates eclipse.desktop file without iteraction with User.

And on the last step I want to add Eclipse.desktop file to Unity Launcher and I do not want to ask user to do it.

I analized the spesification for *.desktop files and did get an answer.

Please provide advice.

Comment: Can you please provide (a small snippet) of your script where you create the .desktop file? We might be able to help you get to a better solution this way. :)

Answer (score 5):

I actually made a script for that. It places the icon down in the launcher, but with a minor change, you can put it at the top (or any other position) as well.

As it is, it is in python2, but simply change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python3` if you'd like to use it as python3. The code is identical.

To use it, the .desktop file needs to be in either `/usr/share/applications` or in `~/.local/share/applications`, but usually that is the case.

#### How to use

- copy the script below, save it as `launcher_add.py`
- make it executable

Run it by the command:

```
/path/to/launcher_add.py name_of_desktopfile.desktop
```

you have to use the *filename* of the .desktop file, without the path.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import sys

desktopfile = sys.argv[1]

def current_launcher():
    get_current = subprocess.check_output(["gsettings", "get", "com.canonical.Unity.Launcher", "favorites"]).decode("utf-8")
    return eval(get_current)

def add_new(desktopfile):
    curr_launcher = current_launcher()
    last = [i for i, x in enumerate(curr_launcher) if x.startswith("application://")][-1]
    new_icon = "application://"+desktopfile
    if not new_icon in curr_launcher:
        curr_launcher.insert(last, new_icon)
        subprocess.Popen(["gsettings", "set", "com.canonical.Unity.Launcher","favorites",str(curr_launcher)])
    else:
        pass

add_new(desktopfile)
```

The script prevents multiple occasions in the launcher list of the same application, which would cause corruption of he list.