# How do you add/remove applications to/from the Unity Launcher from command line?

Tags: unity, command-line, .desktop, uck, launcher

I am customizing an Ubuntu 14.04 Live CD with UCK (Ubuntu Customization Kit). The program gives you a chroot environment in a terminal to make changes.

I want to add and remove what programs appear on the dock.

I'm not sure if this can be accomplished by modifying the `.desktop` file?

How can this be done using the terminal?

Comment: The answer is on [this page](http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/edit-and-create-custom-launcher-icons/): but have no time. Will answer properly soon. http://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor may help as well.

Comment: Aaron, sorry, you'll have to excuse me. I only read your question half. I edited the supposed duplicate from here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/522949/adding-my-launcher-to-the-unity-launcher-automatically-how to add *and* remove items from the launcher from command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script below can be used to either add or remove items to the launcher, depending on the argument(s):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import sys

desktopfile = sys.argv[1]

def current_launcher():
    get_current = subprocess.check_output(["gsettings", "get", "com.canonical.Unity.Launcher", "favorites"]).decode("utf-8")
    return eval(get_current)

def set_launcher(desktopfile):
    curr_launcher = current_launcher()
    last = [i for i, x in enumerate(curr_launcher) if x.startswith("application://")][-1]
    new_icon = "application://"+desktopfile
    if sys.argv[2] == "a":
        if not new_icon in curr_launcher:
            curr_launcher.insert(last, new_icon)
            subprocess.Popen(["gsettings", "set", "com.canonical.Unity.Launcher","favorites",str(curr_launcher)])
    elif sys.argv[2] == "r":
        curr_launcher.remove(new_icon)
        subprocess.Popen(["gsettings", "set", "com.canonical.Unity.Launcher","favorites",str(curr_launcher)])

set_launcher(desktopfile)
```

#### How to run it

1. Paste the code into an empty file, save it as `set_launcher.py`
2. Run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/set_launcher.py <name_of_.desktop_file> a
   ```

   to add an icon, or:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/set_launcher.py <name_of_.desktop_file> r
   ```

   to remove an icon

   Example:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/set_launcher.py gedit.desktop a
   ```

   to add `gedit` to the launcher, or

   ```
   python3 /path/to/set_launcher.py gedit.desktop r
   ```

   to remove `gedit` from the launcher

#### Explanation

The list of launcher icons is defined in the key:

```
com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

and can be fetched by the command:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

to *set* an alternative list (given the fact you use the correct format):

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "[item1, item2, etc]"
```

#### Can you achieve this by editing a `.desktop` file?

No, it has nothing to do with the file itself. What matters is that the file either is in the list of launcher favourites or not.

Editing this list from command line is exactly what the script does.

Comment: is the "set_launcher(desktopfile)" that is currently displayed under the code, actually part of the code?

Comment: @AaronSalyer sharp! indeed, I forgot the indent. fixed it :)

Comment: Thanks for not only providing the code but also the breakdown.  It makes it easier to understand what the script is doing and replicate it in other ways.  This works beautifully in both the UCK environment and my 14.04 install!

Comment: In 18.04, I couldn't find the schema mentioned through `dconf-editor` and anything similar. Some clue where is it stored by now? Thanks!