# Change Image For Launcher Shortcut

Tags: unity, launcher

I created a desktop shortcut that opens Firefox to a particular URL following [these instructions](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-create-desktop-shortcuts-for-websites-in-ubuntu-11-10-tip/). In the instructions they show you how to customize it with a particular image. I was able to do this, but when I drag the shortcut from the desktop to the launcher bar it shows up as a springboard instead of my image. How can I change the image for the icon in the laucher bar? When I right click on the laucher icon the only options are to open it or to remove it from the launcher bar.

Comment: Not a good idea at all to create multiple launchers, running the same application in their main command. Why not make these websites righ-click (quicklist) items of the browser's icon? Anyway, could you post the content of the launcher on pastebin? (open it with gedit) or add it to the question?

Comment: "Not a good idea at all to create multiple launchers, running the same application in their main command." Why not? What terrible thing happens if one does this? I would prefer a separate icon. The launcher points to Firefox and is exactly the same as the one in the linked example, it just points to a different website, but the launch command is simply `firefox http://myurl.com`

Comment: In Unity, in principle, all windows of the same WM_CLASS can be represented by only *one icon at a time*. The consequence is that if you manage to open a firefox window under a different icon (which is possible) additional windows will appear under the same icon, no matter what your website is. This causes (a.o.) clashes in the representation of Firefox. Furthermore: a `.desktop` file of an application comes with a set of keywords, chosen and set by the author, including possible translation, usefull additional keywords etc. A generic launcher may work, but ignores the knowledge of the author.

Comment: ...I can convert [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/789680/72216) to be used with Firefox though. Interested?

Comment: @JacobVlijm, I have not tried it yet, but I can write the script. That should work for my purposes, thanks!

Comment: You can? I already did, I just need to edit it for this one. Would be happy to *and* the question would get answered.  Please just mention and I will.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Sure, I can't complain if you want to help!

Comment: Cool, will post tomorrow 23:48 here :)