# clicking one launcher adds instance on another launcher. how to separate?

Tags: unity, launcher

I have `chrome` and [`empty-chrome`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/empty-chrome)

`empty-chrome` simply starts chrome from webdriver.

I would like to have 2 different icons in the launcher. so I defined a new entry under `/usr/share/applications/empty-chrome.desktop`

[image]

The only problem is that when I click `empty-chrome`, a new instance is added to chrome.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, both are apparently same window class. I mean , `empty-chrome` is still chrome right ?  I doubt there's a way to separate those

Comment: What @Serg sais ^. There *is* however a way to have an application represented multiple instances in the launcher, but would require an edited version of this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/789266/how-can-i-give-a-script-its-own-icon-in-the-unity-launcher. You "normal" chrome icon would appear as well nevertheless. Would be happy to edit though.