# How do I show multiple icons per app in the taskbar?

Tags: unity, icons, taskbar

If I open Atom twice to edit different folders there is still only one icon in the taskbar, not two.

Switching between them constantly by having to click, wait for a preview to display, work out which is which, click it, have the screen refresh and animate is incredibly tedious and annoying.

How do I make each instance of the app have its own icon?

Is there a plugin that will do it for me?

Comment: Windows, belonging to one and the same window class, are represented by one icon in the launcher. A workaround is possible, to show an *additional* icon per instance (window). I would have to edit tis answer though: http://askubuntu.com/a/789680/72216 would that be acceptable to you?

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I do not understand the referenced answer.

Comment: What the linked answer basically does, is show a separate icon per window of an application. In the link, the setup is made for the terminal, but with an edit, it could work for any application. The *native* application icon will show however nevertheless, as a "mother"- icon.

Comment: It's 5 pages long. I'll never get that to work. I was hoping it was an Ubuntu option or something.

Comment: Most of it is explanation. Instructions are only a few steps.

Comment: referred link shows a couple of solutions either specific to scripts or having to build an executable (really?) or some fancy system settings... cmon on ubuntu 17.10 i cant even drop my .desktop files to the launch bar, even if the highlighted icons was latter a mess, we want to do a simple thing! in my case a couple of atom profiles. Is this asking too much? I have the .desktop files on that hidden folder all with proper icons. mac's start to look more customizeable.