# Plank icon to startup script

Tags: command-line, scripts, icons, plank

I want to run the script temp-throttle (https://github.com/Sepero/temp-throttle) **at startup and show a custom Plank icon**.

The script will throttle CPU frequency at 79 celsius if run like so

```
sudo ./temp_throttle.sh 79
```

As it needs the temperature to be specified as above after `cd` in the path of the script, a second script is needed.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

cd "path-to-the-folder//temp-throttle-stable"
terminator -e 'sudo ./temp_throttle.sh 79' --geometry=300x80 -p hold
```

I have called that `temp-throttle` and put it in `$HOME/bin`, as indicated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/465113/47206).

In order to have some info on the situation, I have integrated the command in a terminal command and added `-p hold` that sets a terminal profile to keep terminal window open.

If I add that script to startup applications list, the icon used in Plank is that of the terminal.

[image]

I would like it to run at startup and show in Plank my custom "temp.png" icon

[image]

For that, I have created the file `~/.local/share/applications/temp-throttle.desktop` with the following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=temp-throttle
Icon=temp
Categories=System;Monitor;
Exec=temp-throtle
```

[image]

Executing that directly (double-click) it shows the **terminal** icon in Plank.

I can make the dock use the custom "temp" icon by executing the `.desktop` file from the applications search&launch tool (e.g. Slingshot) or with the command `gtk-launch temp-throttle` (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/664272/47206)).

After that, the custom Plank icon can of course be pinned to the dock (right-click, "Keep in Dock"). That creates the file `/home/cipeos/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/temp-throttle.dockitem` with the lines

```
[PlankDockItemPreferences]
Launcher=file:///home/cipeos/.local/share/applications/temp-throttle.desktop
```

as suggested in the [pauljohn32](https://askubuntu.com/users/495717/pauljohn32)'s answer. He also seems to suggest in a comment that the important thing here is to have the exact same names for all files involved:  all my file are called `temp-throttle`.

The problem is **how to run a `.desktop` file at startup**: if I simply add the desktop file at startup it will not run at all. If I add the startup command  `gtk-launch temp-throttle.desktop` it will still use the terminator icon.

---

This question is close to this: [Apply icons to bash scripts](https://askubuntu.com/q/60667/47206), but different, as the answers under that (use a `.desktop` file) will not work if the command/script/desktop-file is run **at startup**.

It seems that at startup the final command/script is run without taking into account the `Icon=` line in the `.desktop` file, no matter the method used to run the `.desktop` launcher.

I have tested many answers under this question ([Running a .desktop file in the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/5172/47206)) but they will not keep the icon specified in the `.desktop` file if that is run at startup.

---

[THIS](https://askubuntu.com/a/789680/47206) answer provides a solution for Unity, but it doesn't work as such for Plank.

Comment: Which method are you using to launch the program at startup? (.config/autostart, startup applications etc?)

Comment: @Wilf - It's startup applications, `gnome-session-properties`. But will use any other method if it would amount to an answer.

Comment: Will you edit your message and add the content (content example) of the script that will be running as well as the expected output.  This better help me to understand the objective.

Comment: Hi @cipricus if the dupe link is not exactly what you are looking for, please mention.

Comment: @JacobVlijm - I am trying to use the `showicon` script as it seems to be what I want,   but it doesn't work for me at the moment. I still get the terminal icon . --- Is your answer under the other question Unity-specific? I need it to work with Plank.

Comment: @cipricus thanks for mentioning! You might want to add to the question it is for plank :) reopening...

Comment: @JacobVlijm - added Plank in title and tag

Comment: @L.D.James - I think I have posted details here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/344629/32012, it's a script that needs to run in terminal, and for that I have added another script to startup. When it starts at boot it displays the terminal icon in Plank.  Using a desktop file with icon with the latter script isn't providing the dock icon if used at atartup . See the elementaryos link too: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/10696/170

Comment: +1 Finally understood this issue; so far not possible for me. While `.dockitem` method allows to pin `.desktop` file to Plank, the custom icon will only be used when run from the dock. Terminal icon will always be used when run otherwise i.e. application menu, launcher and startup.

Comment: I think that is because your launcher and startup are NOT using the new desktop / script names.  If you can run from terminal and get custom icon in the way I describe, that proves it works.  Now make sure the new desktop and  plank files are using program name that is launched from menu.  See what  I mean? Plank is using default icon "terminal" because it does not  know better because from the startup you are not launching your special script (one named in custom desktop).

Comment: @clearkimura - see my newly edited question

Answer (score 1):

configure a new renamed desktop file that does what you want. Change session manager to launch that one instead of other. Only difference b/t config file will be icon selection.

Here is a concrete example.

1. Open a terminal, run

   $ charmap

Notice the character map pop into the Plank?

2. Right click on the icon, choose "keep in dock".
3. In terminal, cd to ~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers

You should see "gucharmap.dockitem". Edit that file, change the name of the desktop file it is using.

4. You better go create that desktop file you referred to in step 3, or else, well, this whole thing is no fun ;).  I had some fun, for example, by changing the icon for gucharmap in my dock to look exactly like firefox!  The top of my desktop file:

> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Name=Character Map
> Comment=Insert special characters into documents
> Keywords=font;unicode;
> Exec=gucharmap
> Icon=firefox
> ```

All I did was replace the icon with firefox, and now my plank looks twice as awesome.  I think I might  make all of the icons look like firefox.

Now, about your custom script, it is important to get the Exec line correct, or else Plank won't find your script and associate it correctly.  But I think you can get this done.

Comment: I'll double check for an example. I've done this in Window Maker's dock,  ten years ago.  I think we can make same work with Plank. The key element here is that we need the command line strategy to launch a thing into the dock.  To me it is an interesting question.

Comment: Here is an example that shows how. (https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/make-yourself-a-swank-show-desktop-applet-for-plank/363) Name your script, put in a dockitem file under ~./config/plank/dock/launchers, that points at your preferred dekstop file,which controls the icon. Same basic idea here: http://elementarytips.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-add-wine-programs-to-plank.html and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215383/how-to-add-custom-script-to-plank-dock-in-elementary-os-freya

Comment: What you suggested initially is what I already know and mentioned in relation with the askubuntu question [Apply icons to bash scripts](http://askubuntu.com/q/60667/47206). But how to do the same thing at startup?

Comment: @ clearkimura - the dock icon can be added without the need for text editing by creating the desktop in `~/.local/share/applications`, running it from the programs search/launcher and then pinning it (Keep in dock) to Plank.

Comment: I have radically edited my question to make it much more specific, with all details and use of the script. I think **all your indications are followed.** I cannot avoid a second script (to specify the temperature at which the main CPU-throttle script should be executed): temperature cannot be directly set in the desktop file. -  Adding the .desktop path to startup list will not work at all. Adding `gtk-launch <.desktop>` to startup will only follow the Exec= line (the script is executed), but not the Icon= line of that .desktop file (the terminal icon is seen in Plank).