# How to make a command line program have a custom icon in XFCE dock or Plank?

Tags: icons, xfce, desktop-icons, plank

I have created a .desktop file for `octave-cli`, which is the command line version of GNU Octave. When I double click the .desktop file (which has the icon of Octave, and is pinned in XFCE Panel), the opened terminal window has a icon of Terminal (not of Octave).

Is there a way to make command line programs use their own icons throughout?

This also happens when I drag the .desktop file to a dock like Plank.

[image]

[image]

To clarify, the .desktop file does have the icon I had set. But when I double click it, it opens in a terminal with a *terminal icon*. I want it to open in a terminal (obviously) with a *octave* icon, to make it look like a standalone software.

Comment: Can't you change the icon if you edit the *.desktop* file with a text editor and add the `Icon=whatever.png` line?

Comment: @Stormlord Check the updated question

Comment: This link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/789266/how-can-i-give-a-script-its-own-icon-in-the-unity-launcher addresses the issue for the unity launcher. Does it help in your case? With a few modifications maybe?

Comment: The python program in that answer only works in Unity. In my computer it searches for Unity and crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to do it in Ubuntu Gnome 20.04. Not sure if it works in your DE, but you may be able to adapt it https://askubuntu.com/a/1361035/1064531

Comment: Does not work.
`xfce4-terminal -e "micro %F" -t "Micro" --hide-menubar --name=Micro --class=micro` the output is
`xfce4-terminal: Unknown option "-t"`. It does not work unless `-t` `--name` and `--class` is removed, but then it would have the same icon as the terminal.

Comment: I installed gnome-terminal in xfce. There the command works, but the icon is still the terminal icon.